# g-wan main.c - to listen to sockets

Tags: key-value-store, g-wan

I want to fork a sub-program to do some routine jobs or listen to some sockets.
If this can be done, please show with a simple example how this forked program can access the G-WAN KV store via a persistent pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to execute a third-party program rather than forking G-WAN.

If you `fork()` G-WAN, you will have a second process that fails to listen to the `host definitions` already used by the first instance of G-WAN to listen on IPs and port numbers.

Starting from there, you should rather use the `maintenance` script or launch a third-party program (which will not share the memory address space of G-WAN).

Now, you can't share in-memory KV stores between processes yet - but this is on our TODO list.

Comment: what if, in main.c, i use pthread to execute a function (ansi c script including gwan.h), can this function access the KV store?

Comment: Yes, this would work (either with a handler or a servlet); pass the kv_store pointer to the thread. Note that such a thread could also listen on free port numbers. You can create as many thread you wish but it would be wise to create the one(s) you need at startup with a static variable like: firsttime = 1; if(firsttime) { firsttime = 0; phread_create(); }